# Convergence of a sequence and another sequence is bounded

Tags: convergence-divergence

Prove: If the sequence $<a_{n}>$ converges to $0$, and the sequence $<b_{n}>$ is bounded, then the sequence $<a_{n}b_{n}>$ also converges to $0$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}<a_{n}> = 0$  applying the definition of the limit $$|a_{n}| = |a_{n} - 0| < \epsilon \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
Then, $$|a_{n}b_{n} - 0| = |a_{n}b_{n}| < \epsilon \ \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

I am not sure if I am right, any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: $|a_nb_n|\le \epsilon M$ where $M=\sup_n|b_n|$.

Comment: So, I am guessing I am wrong?

Comment: There are 2 mistakes:
1. not for all $n\in\mathbb N$, it must be changed with "sufficiently large $n$'s" 2. $\epsilon M$. But your proof is nearly correct.

Comment: Could you write out how I would correct those mistakes to complete my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy for this proof is this: since $a_n \to 0$ we can make $a_n$ arbitrarily small and since $b_n$ is bounded we know that there is a bound on the size of $|b_n|$. Hence, we will make $|a_n|$ small enough so that $|a_n b_n|$ is always less than $\epsilon$. Here is a proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $b_n$ is bounded then there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ |b_n| < M $$ for all $n > 0$. 
Since $a_n\to0$ then we can choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n| < \epsilon/M$ for all $n \ge N$. Hence, for all $n\ge N$ we have
$$
|a_n b_n| < M|a_n| < M\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon.$$

Therefore, $|a_n b_n| \to 0$.